# How to solve this ubuntu screen problem?

Tags: 18.04, display, screen

[image: weird lines]
[image: weird teaskbar]

Sometimes I can not even read any text, every file name character is replaced by a block.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: well what did you do to get there? what is your hardware? is this from day one after installing ubuntu? what ubuntu version and kernel?

Comment: This seems like a hardware issue (even though we have no idea what that hardware is). I would check your connections to your display adapter and the gpu (if there is one) connection to the machine. Otherwise, it may just be a bad GPU (like those old AMD's in the HP laptops that needed to be reballed from overheating). Without more info though this is just 100% speculation.

Comment: @tatsu I am using ubuntu for 2 years.2 months back I reinstalled my Ubuntu after that I'm facing this problem. processor : Intel® Core™ i3-2330M CPU @ 2.20GHz × 4  and graphics : Intel® Sandybridge Mobile  and 64 bit computer dell Vostro 3550

Comment: huh maybe popos can fix it. they are basically ubuntu but with intergrated intel drivers. how about you  try that?

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with graphics driver, have you tried updating your pc? try `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` to update and upgrade